# Dynamically add values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add values using a `for` loop in JavaScript. I can't figure out how to compare each value in my `new Array` named section2answers.

I created two arrays. One that holds all the values I am comparing which is called radios. And another array that is empty to hold the values that pass the first arrays condition.

Then I have two `for` loops. One that goes through all the possible answers and determines which one of those are `true` for being checked.

And another `for` loop that goes through the values that passed the condition in the first loop. This loop then checks each value in the new loop to determine if they match a correct answer and then assigns a score value to be output to an input field.

I have a couple problems I can see. My first `for` loop is not properly comparing each element in the array to my condition.

My second problem is my second `for` loop is only using the element that was initially clicked on instead of comparing to each of the `if` conditions. And as with the first loop, I don't think it is comparing each value in the loop the the set of `if` conditions.

Also, if the user decides to change their answer I can't figure out a way to subtract from the total value.

I would like to create something that runs these loops every time a radio button is clicked to give the new total.

Code:

HTML

```
<div class="block-margin">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="bold">1. How long is the battery life on the PicoPix PPX 2340 Traveller?</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no1-two-hours" id="test">Two hours</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no1-two-hours" name="NO1_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO1aTwoHours" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no1-90-minutes">90 minutes</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no1-90-minutes" name="NO1_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO1a90minutes" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no1-one-hour">One hour</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no1-one-hour" name="NO1_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO1aOneHour" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no1-five-hours">Five hours</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no1-five-hours" name="NO1_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO1aFiveHours" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="block-margin">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                        <div class="bold">2. What size is the ladies & gents Eternity Summer?</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no2-50ml">50ml</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no2-50ml" name="NO2_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO2a250ml" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no2-75ml">75ml</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no2-75ml" name="NO2_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO2a75ml" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no2-125ml">125ml</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no2-125ml" name="NO2_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO2a125ml" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 form-group">
                                <label for="no2-100ml">100ml</label>
                                <input type="radio" id="no2-100ml" name="NO2_ANSWER_CHOICES" value="NO2a100ml" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function () {
            var section2a1 = document.getElementById('no1-two-hours');
            var section2a2 = document.getElementById('no2-100ml');
            var section2a3 = document.getElementById('no3-almond');
            var section2a4 = document.getElementById('no4-2years');
            var section2a5 = document.getElementById('no5-reveal');
            var section2a6 = document.getElementById('no6-mild');
            var section2a7 = document.getElementById('no7-60');
            var section2a8 = document.getElementById('no8-110');
            var section2a9 = document.getElementById('no9-80cm');
            var section2a10 = document.getElementById('no10-two');
            var total = 0;
            var radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
            var section2answers = new Array ();
            for (i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
                if ($('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked')) {
                    section2answers.push(this);
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<section2answers.length; i++) {
                if (this == section2a1) {
                    total += 4;
                } else if (this == section2a2) {
                    total += 4;
                }
            }
            $('#ints-right-two').val(total);
        });
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can re-create the issue.

Comment: that's not the problem. jQuery object and js (this) seem to both work fine that I can tell in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think that `this` inside the loop refers to the array element at the current index. It does not. It is still the object that was used as the context to call the function that contains the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  if ($(radios[i]).prop('checked')) {
    section2answers.push(radios[i]);
  }
}
for (i = 0; i < section2answers.length; i++) {
  if (section2answers[i] == section2a1) {
    total += 4;
  } else if (section2answers[i] == section2a2) {
    total += 4;
  }
}
```

Comment: nvm dude. I had up the wrong file in my localhost. This seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: And you're correct about the misunderstanding of 'this'. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

in the first `for` loop, you're using `$('input[type="radio"]')` in the if statement. This will always return u the `prop` of the first radio button. you can try `$('input[type="radio"]').eq(i)`, as `i` is the `i` in your first for loop.

Comment: sorry i mislooked, your context is in the onChange event callback